# Add movie as separate audio/video track?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have the top window selected as video editing and the bottom window set as video sequence editor.

When I add a movie to the video sequence editor, it imports as a combined track with audio and video combined on one line. Without closing the project, if I add the same movie file to the same video sequence editor, it now imports as separate audio and video tracks. I have tried different movie clip sources and get the same result.

Is there a preset that causes this and/or is there a magic handshake that separates the first import, video from audio.
I am using Blender 2.76 on Linux Mint 18.

Reset to *Factory Defaults* then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to save and all works now as expected.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please do not add "solved" to the question title. Please accept your answer instead. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is weird. I installed this same Blender version 2.76 on another machine also running LM 18 directly from the Software Manager and it behaves as expected. The movie clip is added as separate video and audio lines.
Thinking the "troubled" machine had a corrupt Blender install, I uninstalled and reinstalled Blender, also directly from the Software Manager, and I get the same wonky results where the audio and video files appear to be superimposed on the same line.
If I add the same video without closing the project, the second time it loads as separate video and audio tracks.

solved:
Reset to Factory Defaults then CtrlU to save and all works now as expected.